# Для чего в коде стоит знак *?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print(*(lambda a, b: (b, a))(int(input()), int(input())))
```

Answer (score 4):

Не ленитесь проверять разные варианты кода самостоятельно, ведь у питона есть интерактивный интерпретатор (и не один), в котором проверить разные варианты кода - дело нескольких секунд.

```
print(*(lambda a, b: (b, a))(int(input()), int(input())))
```

Вывод, если ввести 10 и 20:

```
20 10
```

А теперь убираем `*` и снова пробуем:

```
print((lambda a, b: (b, a))(int(input()), int(input())))
```

Вывод, если ввести 10 и 20:

```
(20, 10)
```

`*` разворачивает коллекцию, к которой она применяется, на отдельные элементы. Как можно видеть, без `*` печатается кортеж как он есть, а со `*` элементы коллекции (в данном случае - кортежа) выводятся на печать так, как будто это набор отдельных переменных. Иногда это бывает полезно (и далеко не только для печати).

Comment: [даю тонкий намёк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1273305/%d0%94%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba#comment2241736_1273305) на предложение не лениться ещё и при поиске дубликатов.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Ленюсь, да )

Comment: @crazyElf, Спасибо